# unix sort command doesnt work in shell script

Tags: shell

I am trying to execute simple sort command in shell script as below -

```
exec sort -t',' -k6nr,6 temp1 -o temp2
```

It doesnt work at all.
However, the same sort command "

```
sort -t',' -k6nr,6 temp1 -o temp2
```

works perfectly fine in command line.

Any help would be of great help here.

Comment: Why are you using `exec` before `sort`?

Comment: How else you can execute within the shell script?

Comment: Just call `sort` directly as you're doing on command line

Comment: In BASH you would not use exec like this.  You would use command substitution.  `output=$(sort -t',' -k6nr,6 temp1 -o temp2)`

Comment: I am not using the exec command on command line, I want to run within the shell script, foe ex as below -#!/bin/sh
#\
cd `dirname $0`
#\
exec tclsh `basename $0` $@

exec sed 1d $path/$top15Buy > temp1
exec sort -k 6,6n temp1 -o temp2

Comment: @shremouse , I am not using bash, I am using c shell.

Comment: it doesn't matter, csh/ksh/bash/tcsh/zsh/.... . You don't need `exec` to run `sort`. Did you try just using `sort ...` in your script? If this is working now, please delete this question as it will not help others in the future. Good luck.

Comment: Haven't tried without exec, will try and check, if it works fine,then will delete it

Comment: It doesn't work without the exec command.I am getting the below error -invalid command name "sort"
    while executing
"sort -k 6,6g temp1 -o temp2"

Comment: you say you're using 'c shell'. Why does your command in the comment above begin with `#!/bin/sh`? Please edit your question to include a complete but small working sample of all of your code. Are you running this script from inside another environment, like java, ruby or 100 other possibilities, or via a `system()` function? If so you'll need to include that info to. As others have said, `exec` inside a shell script will give you results you don't intend. Good luck.